# Preventing duplicate '@' symbols in email address via SQL Query

Tags: sql

Is there anyway (Query in SQL) that prevents multiple entry of '@' Symbol in Email Address 
                                  OR
Is there anyway (Query in SQL) that counts How many times '@' Symbol comes in an Email Address?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres?...

Comment: Anyway, the easiest way would be some variation of `SELECT LEN('somestringwithan@inthemiddle')-LEN(REPLACE('somestringwithan@inthemiddle','@',''))`

Comment: How is the data getting _in_ to SQL Server?  Seems more appropriate to fix it there than updating the data in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In most databases you would use a `check` constraint:

```
create table . . . (
    . . .
    check (Email not like '%@%@%')
```

Or:

```
alter table . . .
    add constraint chk_NoDoubleAmpersands (Email not like '%@%@%'
```

If the database doesn't support check constraints, then you would use a trigger.

Comment: I read "preventing multiple entries of @" as only allowing one on the whole string, not necessarily that they need to be consecutive

Comment: @Lamak . . . That is a really good comment.  I fixed the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily converted to a stored procedure.  [sql-2008]

This query will return the original text (email address) and the also include a column stating if the address passes the '@' test.  This base code can also be modified to look if the substring after the '@' has at least one '.' IN THE ADDRESS STRING.

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(50) = 'some_email@site.tld'
DECLARE @testValue AS VARCHAR(50) = @S
DECLARE @PF AS BIT = 'FALSE'
WHILE PatIndex('%[^@]%', @testvalue) > 0
    SET @testValue = Stuff(@testValue, PatIndex('%[^@]%', @testValue), 1, '')
SET @PF = CASE WHEN LEN(@testValue) = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
IF @PF = 'TRUE' SET @PF = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',@S,CHARINDEX('@',@S)) > 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
SELECT @S, @PF AS is_valid
```

If more that one @ exist then the length of @testValue will be greater than 1.  The @PF var first validates length = 1 else all other values fail.  Next @PF if 'true' it checks if at least 1 '.' exist in the address after the '@' denoting a valid format. This by no means validates if the site and the tld (top level domain) exist.